# How to parse through JSON via dot notation

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to grab the values of some nested JSON objects, and the paths are in in dot notation.
Meaning:

```
{  
   "parent":{  
      "child":{  
         "grandchild":"value"
      }
   }
}
```

equals

`parent.child.grandchild`.

The problem is the depths are variable. If it was a fixed length, I could use an enhanced for loop and then just add the keys to the "with" statement in Jackson to grab the value. Any direction on how I can accomplish this with variable depths?

Comment: You may be looking for JsonPath, see e.g. [here](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html) and [here](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

Comment: If you want to implement it yourself, just split the path expression at the separators (`'.'`) and then recursively traverse the JSON elements until the end of the path is reached.

Comment: "I could use an enhanced for loop and then just add the keys to the "with" statement in Jackson to grab the value. Any direction on how I can accomplish this with variable depths?" - What do you mean by "variable depth"? Length of the path? Depth of the hierarchy of JSON objects? Why should the code be any different for fixed or variable lengths?

Comment: Yes JSONPath was exactly what I was looking, but I think I will do it recursively. Thank you both!